# Dynamically set columns to filter with ORM in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, orm

I cannot figure out how to set columns dynamically for filtering using the latest SQLalchemy style for ORM.

Basically, I want to create a wrapper function to be able to pass in any columns into the 'where' part of the statement, the idea would be:

```
def get_id(column, value):
    id = session.execute(select(Account.id).where(
       Account.column == value)).all()

    return id
```

My problem is that I cannot dynamically select the attribute of the Account object with `Account[column]` as I get the error: *TypeError: 'DeclarativeMeta' object is not subscriptable*

I know this is possible with Core by setting up table MetaData and using either `account.c[column]` or the `column()` function  but I would be interested in an ORM solution as my tables are automapped.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can use reflection features of Python, like this.

```
column_name = 'name';
getattr(Account, column_name) # This is equivalent to Account.name
```

But you can also use a ready-made API like this.

```
ids = [id for id, in session.query(Account.id).filter_by(**{column_name: value}).all()]
```

See [Query API](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html).

Comment: Ah, yes thanks, I totally forgot ```getattr```, that works well!